# Rails: has_many within timeframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails application with a `Comment` model, and a `Notification` model, where each Comment `has_many :notifications`

I want to set up a `dependent: :destroy` on this `has_many` relationship. The problem is that the notifications table is HUGE (somewhere in the order of 20 million records). So any time I try to destroy a comment, it spends several minutes looking through the notifications table.

Usually when I query the notifications table, I just specify a range for the `created_at`, and that seems to work pretty well.

All of the notifications are created within 24 hours of the comment's `created_at` - So I figured to speed up the relationship, I could just add something like

```
has_many :notifications, -> { where(created_at: created_at..(created_at + 1.day)) }, dependent: :destroy
```

But of course that doesn't work because `created_at` is being called on an instance of `Notification::ActiveRecord_Relation`, not on the original comment.

Is there anyway to reference an attribute of a comment in that comment's `has_many` query?

Comment: Not answering your question, but do you need to `:destroy` the notifications or could you `:delete` them? that should be a lot faster. Alternatively you could remove the dependency and fire off a background job to clean them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the association definition, you can reference the comment **passed as a block parameter**:

```
has_many :notifications, 
            -> (comment) { where(created_at: comment.created_at..(comment.created_at + 1.day)) }, 
            dependent: :destroy
```

See the *[Accessing the owner object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Accessing+the+owner+object)* section of docs for more info.

Comment: Woah, thats awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Use `joins` to reference the child class within the where statement:

```
has_many :notifications, -> { joins(:notifications).where(notifications: { created_at: created_at..(created_at + 1.day) }, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Thanks for the response here, this should work, but i think @BoraMa's answer is a little simpler, and slightly more efficient, because it doesn't need to do a join and instead uses `rails magic`.